# SIZING steps and Interpreting Mosfet datasheet

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, maximum-ratings, reverse-polarity, powermosfet

After reading those

[Interpreting Maximum Power of a MOSFET from the datasheet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267447/interpreting-maximum-power-of-a-mosfet-from-the-datasheet)

[How to interpret Vgs(th) min/max in a MOSFET datasheet?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312172/how-to-interpret-vgsth-min-max-in-a-mosfet-datasheet)

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_Linear_Mode_Operation_Safe_Operation_Diagram_MOSFETs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433e30e4bf013e3646e9381200

[image]
what i understand :

**clarify coniditons :**

fet calculation :

1)Vgs min  :

from zero thermal coeffcient , from gaph : Ids , Vgs , to prevent thermal runaway

2)Vgs max : from datasheet Vgss

3)Vds max :  From Safe operating Area graph , before thermal instability line,        and keep in mind power limit .

---

**project calculation :**

1) first model my load , to know its impedance , resistance 
2) calculate Vds = Vbattery - Load Voltage drop  , Vd = Vb  , Vs = Vd-Vds

( stated in pdf that Vds depends on voltage drop of load )

3) controlling Vg so it can be variable or constant , connect it to ground so it becomes zero

4) calculate Id ,from Id , Vds graph at known Vgs

**Does these steps are correct , fully understood or i miss something  ?**

---

i want to know in Ids ( Vds graph )

**is linear region ,  when Vds before V pinch ? and this region correspond to Rds on limit in SOA graph  ?**

**also does saturation region corresponds to package limited ?**

**if these are correct what does max power limit corresponds to in Ids Vds graph ?**

[image]

Comment: Where did you find schematic with load and supply on wrong sides

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  sorry i dont understand what do u mean

Comment: Swap supply and load if you want correct polarity.

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Reverse-Batery-Protection-Rev2.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b41887722615

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 please read this , u will find they use it the same way like im using , also i have already tested and simulated it and works fine , actually im asking about sizing and doing calculations